# c# serial port data mix close to the 0 reading

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am a beginner at C# and would like some advice on how to solve the following problem:

My main code is while loop where I comunicate with 24bit ADC to read voltage and current and plot calculated data.

Code first send the register name 1 and read command for first register. Than code wait for ReadInt24(stream) to read incoming data, calculate voltage and plot calculated voltage. Then code send register name 2 and read command, wait for ReadInt24(stream) to read incoming data, calculate current, plot calculated current and everything spins in a loop again.

When I read some voltage and current everything work as it should, but when I want to read voltage and current with open clamps (measure my zero voltage and current to set the offset), every few cycles I get  high voltage or high current spikes, but mostly measures closet to the 0. I think that my data are mixing when I want to measure voltage and current close to the zero (open clamps or set 0 voltage and 0current on the power supply).

I think that measuring values close to the 0 (24 bit adc reading example at low values 00110000 00000000 0000000 ) data are mixing because of receiving bits with almost all 0 values.

What could I add to code that to fix those spikes?

I analyzed send and receive data with logic analyzer and all incomming (24bit) data are correct. I use ADS122U04 ADC.

Please ignor my bad english.

```
private async Task read()
    {
      Stream stream = serialPort1.BaseStream;

       while (read_data_on)
          {
        stream.Write(new byte[] { 0x55, 0x40, 0x05 }, 0, 3); //set register 1
        stream.Write(new byte[] { 0x55, 0x1c }, 0, 2); //read register 1
        vrednost1 = await ReadInt24(stream); 

           v = ((((4.096 / 16777216) * vrednost1) / 4) * 250); //calculate voltage               
           this.chrNapetost.Series["Series1"].Points.AddY(v); //plot voltage

        stream.Write(new byte[] { 0x55, 0x40, 0x65 }, 0, 3); //set register 2
        stream.Write(new byte[] { 0x55, 0x1c }, 0, 2); //read register 2
        vrednost2 = await ReadInt24(stream); 

          a = ((((4.096 / 16777216) * vrednost2) / 4) / 0.1); //calculate current
          this.chrNapetost.Series["Series1"].Points.AddY(a); //plot current
          } 
      }

  private async Task<int> ReadInt24(Stream stream)
     {
        byte[] input = new byte[3];
        int offset = 0;

          while (offset < input.Length)
            {
         offset += await stream.ReadAsync(input, offset, input.Length - offset);
            }

        return (input[2] << 16) | (input[1] << 8) | (input[0]);
   }
```

My serial port settings:

```
            serialPort1.PortName = cBoxCOMPORT.Text;
            serialPort1.BaudRate = Convert.ToInt32("115200");
            serialPort1.DataBits = Convert.ToInt32("8");
            serialPort1.StopBits = System.IO.Ports.StopBits.One;
            serialPort1.Parity = System.IO.Ports.Parity.None;
```

Comment: what is the format in which the ADC is sending the data?

Comment: 8-N-1 Format, baud rate is set to 115200, adc have auto baud rate up to 120k.

Comment: My first guess wouldn't be your code, although I'd factor out the formulas and unit test them. But if you have reasonable readings for reasonable input and unexpected values for extreme inputs, maybe your communication is right, but your sensor is going nuts?

Comment: ^^ In other words: I think your problem is on the electrical engineering part, not the software engineering part. You do use some sort of pull-down resistors, don't you? (Maybe take your setup to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ but check their "what can I ask here" - section)

Comment: You are right, mybe spikes are ADC problem. I find out that you can filer spikes out with software (check last value and if is huge difference filter it out).